# Simplify/RESTify my routes!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

Here is a sample of my routes.rb
Basically I have users that have pictures and that can rate other people's pictures

This is not very RESTful at all, but I cannot figure out how to turn this around?

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      post :reset_password
    end
  end
  # to list images
  get 'images/list/:order/:page/:per_page/:category', :to => 'images#list_filtered'
  # to rate images
  post 'images/rate', :to => 'images#rate'
  # to list a user's images
  get 'images/user/:user_id/:category/:order/:page/:per_page', :to => "images#user"
  # to list users that rated an image
  get 'users/rated/:image_id', :to => 'users#rated'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things I would recommend:

1. Use images#index instead of images#list_filtered and pass order, page, per_page and category as parameter: /images?order=...&per_page=...&page=...
2. Make images nested under users as resources and then make images a top level resource that is independent of user (so that you can view all images or you can view user specific images).

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :reset_password
  end
  resources :images
end

resources :images do
  post :rate
  get :rated
end
```

You should then be able to view images using /images.

You should be able to rate an individual image using /images/:id/rate.

You should be able to view users who rated an image using /images/:id/rated.

You should be able to list a user's images using /user/:id/images.

Comment: but /images and /user/:id/images both go to :action => "index", :controller => "images", how do I handle this nicely?

Comment: You have a couple of choices, but the easiest is to simply check for the presence of the 'user_id' parameter, since it will only be passed if the images are being called from the nested resource.  If your functions begin to diverge a lot - for example if you are using entirely different views for each case, then it's time to create two separate actions with different names, or to create an additional nested User::ImagesController that handles the nested actions.

Comment: it's actually a case that I have more in my routing (which much more complex than the example I gave), 2 separate actions takes away from the nice URL design I intend to have but I am interested in what you say by "create an additional nested User::ImagesController that handles the nested actions", how do I do that?

Comment: You simply need to nest your controllers in modules ("class Users::ImagesController...") and then specify that controller in your routes ("resources :images, :controller => 'Users::Images'") instead of using the default.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you treat images and ratings as resources? Nest images under their users and add a **Rating** model that belongs to an image and a user (the user giving the rating, not the owner of the rated image)

```
resources :users do
  resources :images do
    resources :ratings, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
  post :reset_password, :on => :member
end
```

then you can set up your cotroller like this

```
# ratings_controller.rb
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_image

  # POST /users/26/images/351/ratings
  def create
    @image.ratings.create(params[:rating])
    redirect_to image_path(@image), :notice => "You just rated this image"
  end

  # DELETE /users/26/images/351/ratings/35477
  def destroy
    @image.ratings.find(params[:id]).destroy!
    redirect_to image_path(@image), :notice => "Deleted rating"
  end

  private

  def find_image
    @image = Image.where(:user_id => params[:user_id], :id => params[:image_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i was about to do for a little project i'm working on, needed some confirmation, awesome!